# In which cases does std::optional operator == cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_cmp) has the following description of mixed (optional and some other non-optional type) comparison operators for `std::optional`:

> Compares opt with a value. The values are compared (using the
> corresponding operator of T) only if opt contains a value. Otherwise,
> opt is considered less than value. If the corresponding two-way
> comparison expression between *opt and value is not well-formed, or if
> its result is not convertible to bool, the behavior is undefined.

What confuses me here is:

- What would be examples of these not well-formed comparisons?
- Why don't compilers/STL just reject the invalid comparisons instead of giving us UB?

Comment: Just a guess: `T` having a strange `T::operator==`

Comment: Or not having `operator==` at all? Not sure why it's UB rather than ill-formed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This stems from imprecise specification, which has since been rectified.

In [C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/optional.relops), these comparisons were specified as:

> *Requires*: The expression `*x == *y` shall be well-formed and its result shall be convertible to `bool`.

Requires was a precondition, so failing to meet these conditions would be [undefined behavior](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/library#res.on.required-1). But there are many different kinds of "preconditions" - does it mean check this statically, does this mean remove the operator from the overload set if the conditions aren't met, does it mean actual undefined behavior?

In [C++20](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.relops), these are instead specified as:

> *Mandates*: The expression `*x == *y` is well-formed and its result is convertible to `bool`.

Which [means](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#structure.specifications-3.2) that the program is ill-formed if the conditions aren't met. Basically, a mandate is a `static_assert` (or equivalent).

So yes, the standard library is obligated to reject types whose comparison either doesn't exist or doesn't give you something like a `bool`. This was never actually going to give you undefined behavior (what would an implementation do if it didn't have such an operator, read a bit from `/dev/random`?) but now it's just much more clearly specified.

---

These changes came from a series of papers by Marshall Clow entitled "Mandating the Standard Library", this one specifically from [P1460](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1460r1.pdf) (thanks, Marshall!). The new terminology for specifying the standard library comes from Walter Brown's "Guidelines for Formulating Library Semantics Specifications" paper ([P1369](https://wg21.link/p1369%5D)).

Comment: upvoted, but I am not sure why you are quoting specification that dereferences both x and y, I would presume in cases I ask about only one side is dereferenced. I presume this limitation was also for comparison of optional<T> and optional<U> so the answer still has the same conclusion.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Because all the comparisons are worded the same so I just picked the first one.

Comment: "what would an implementation do if it didn't have such an operator?" Return `FileNotFound`, of course.